# How to store exponential values (1.3e12) and normal values(1.3) in the same matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting, floating-point-precision

I have a file consisting of values ranging from 0.1 to 1.3e12. I have been trying it to store in the same array but its not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? how large is the file - now many values?

Comment: @user1483180 Where's your code? Without code, no-one can tell you where you went wrong...

Comment: @user1483180: I'm thinking your issue has to do with number formatting (when printed in the command prompt)? need more info..

Comment: Sure its working. help format.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers 0.1 and 1.3e12 are both stored in floating point data type.  The `double` type is the default for storing either of these in Matlab.  So the answer is *Yes* you can store them in the same matrix.

What you are *actually* referring to is the way the numbers are *formatted* for viewing.  Please have a look at the [documentation for `format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html)